# Correctly handling sendBroadcast() from an IntentService

Tags: android, android-intent, intentservice

I'm using an `IntentService` to fetch data from a remote source. When the service has fetched the data, it broadcasts it using `sendBroadcast(intent)`.

In my main activity, I extend `BroadcastReceiver` and define an `onReceive()` to handle the data sent by `sendBroadcast()`.

I register the receiver in `onResume()` using `registerReceiver(...)` and unregister it in `onPause()` using `unregisterReceiver()`. This is in accordance with what is recommended in http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html.

If `sendBroadcast()` broadcasts data while the activity is in `onPause()` (where the receiver has been unregistered), the broadcast goes unhandled. If the `onPause()` is followed by an `onResume()`, the receiver is registered again, but the IntentService has already done its work and there is nothing for receiver to listen to. Question: Is there is a good pattern for letting the activity know that the broadcast has already happened?

Comment: Use EventBus like GreenRobot's EventBus, or OTTO - it will be much easier to deal with.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski Yeah ! :)

Comment: why dont you use a Notification or bound service pattern?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about how you can with your current scenario but developers do same thing in a different ways.

They use **EventBus** ([Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/), [GreenRobot's EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus)) that is designed for same purpose which you are doing and it do job very nicely.

So use it and you will find it interesting.